# Failure to create two sibling nodes in the root node using libxml2 writer handler

Tags: libxml2

I am new to libxml2 trying to generate XML files for the first time. But unable to create sibling node in the root node when try to create an XML file via [testWriter.c](http://www.xmlsoft.org/examples/index.html#testWriter.c) link,The libxml2 will print an error message.

**I want to create this example xml file. The point that there are sibling nodes in the root node:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <!--child1 comment-->
    <child1>
        <element11>value11</element11>
        <element11>12</element11>
    </child1>

    <!--child2 comment-->
    <child2>
        <element21>value21</element21>
        <element22>22</element22>
    </child2>
</root>
```

**My writer handler code:**

```c
static void
gen_child1(xmlTextWriterPtr writer) {
    char buf[64];

    // comment
    xmlTextWriterWriteComment(writer, BAD_CAST "child1 comment");

    // start
    if( xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "child1") < 0 )
        return;

    // add a child element
    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element11", BAD_CAST "value11");

    // add a child element
    (void) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", 12);
    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element12", BAD_CAST buf);

    // start new node
    if( xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element13") < 0 )
        return;

    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element131", BAD_CAST "value131");

    // end new node
    xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);

    // end
    xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
}


static void
gen_child2(xmlTextWriterPtr writer) {
    char buf[64];

    // comment
    xmlTextWriterWriteComment(writer, BAD_CAST "child2 comment");

    // start
    if( xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "child2") < 0 )
        return;

    // add a child element
    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element21", BAD_CAST "value21");

    // add a child element
    (void) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", 22);
    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element22", BAD_CAST buf);

    // start new node
    if( xmlTextWriterStartElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element23") < 0 )
        return;

    xmlTextWriterWriteElement(writer, BAD_CAST "element231", BAD_CAST "value231");

    // end new node
    xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);

    // end
    xmlTextWriterEndElement(writer);
}


static void
gen_doc(void) {
    xmlTextWriterPtr writer = NULL;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr root;

    if( !(doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST XML_DEFAULT_VERSION)) )
        puts("xmlNewDoc() failure");

    if( !(root = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, BAD_CAST "root", NULL)) )
        puts("xmlNewDocNode() failure");

    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);

    // create writer
    if( !(writer = xmlNewTextWriterTree(doc, root, 0)) )
        puts("xmlNewTextWriterTree() failure");

    // start doc
    if( xmlTextWriterStartDocument(writer, NULL, ENCODING, NULL) < 0 )
        puts("xmlTextWriterStartDocument() failure");

    gen_child1(writer);
    gen_child2(writer);

    // end doc
    xmlTextWriterEndDocument(writer);

    // free writer
    xmlFreeTextWriter(writer);

    print_doc(doc);
}
```

**Libxml2 print this error message:**

```sh
# This is Libxml2 output:
Entity: line 2: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
nt13><element131>value131</element131></element13></child1><!--child2 comment-->
                                                                               ^
error : xmlTextWriterWriteDocCallback : XML error 5 !
I/O error : flush error
error : xmlTextWriterCloseDocCallback : XML error 5 !

# This is my print_doc(doc) output:
Length: 224
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root><!--child1 comment--><child1><element11>value11</element11><element12>12</element12><element13><element131>value131</element131></element13></child1></root>
<!--child2 comment-->
```

**I will succeed without using the writer handler, this the code:**

```c
static xmlNodePtr
gen_child1(xmlNsPtr _ns, const xmlChar *_name) {
    xmlNodePtr retval = xmlNewNode(_ns, _name);
    char buf[64];

    if( retval ) {
        xmlNewTextChild(retval, _ns, BAD_CAST "element11", BAD_CAST "value11");

        (void) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", 12);
        xmlNewTextChild(retval, _ns, BAD_CAST "element11", BAD_CAST buf);
    }

    return retval;
}


static xmlNodePtr
gen_child2(xmlNsPtr _ns, const xmlChar *_name) {
    xmlNodePtr retval = xmlNewNode(_ns, _name);
    char buf[64];

    if( retval ) {
        xmlNewTextChild(retval, _ns, BAD_CAST "element21", BAD_CAST "value21");

        (void) snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d", 22);
        xmlNewTextChild(retval, _ns, BAD_CAST "element22", BAD_CAST buf);
    }

    return retval;
}


static void
gen_doc(void) {
    xmlTextWriterPtr writer = NULL;
    xmlDocPtr doc;
    xmlNodePtr root;

    if( !(doc = xmlNewDoc(BAD_CAST XML_DEFAULT_VERSION)) )
        puts("xmlNewDoc() failure");

    if( !(root = xmlNewDocNode(doc, NULL, BAD_CAST "root", NULL)) )
        puts("xmlNewDocNode() failure");

    xmlDocSetRootElement(doc, root);

    xmlAddChild(root, xmlNewComment(BAD_CAST "child1 comment"));
    xmlAddChild(root, gen_child1(NULL, BAD_CAST "child1"));

    xmlAddChild(root, xmlNewComment(BAD_CAST "child2 comment"));
    xmlAddChild(root, gen_child2(NULL, BAD_CAST "child2"));

    print_doc(doc);

    xmlFreeDoc(doc);
}
```

**I want to know what i did wrong when using the writer handler?**

Comment: Please read the descriptions of the tags you applied and fix them! Further, please provide a [mcve], not separate snippets of code. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

`xmlNewTextWriterTree` has never been implemented correctly in libxml2.

The `xmlTextWriter` API should only be used to write documents in serialized form. Functions like `xmlNewTextWriterTree` or `xmlNewTextWriterDoc` serialize and reparse XML which is really inefficient. It's better to build documents using the "tree" API like in your working example.

You could open a bug report, but this badly designed part of the code base is unlikely to get fixed.